# Property of an irreducible Markov Chain

Tags: probability-theory, markov-chains, markov-process

How can we prove that if a Markov Chain is irreducible (does not contain any closed set), then every state can be reached from every other state in the chain ?

Comment: the entire markov chain is always a closed set

Comment: But even in a closed probability of reaching one state from another can be zero. Closeness only implies that the next state has to be an element of the closed set.